# How to acesses dictionary elements within a pandas dataframe column and iterate over them too create new columns filled with their respective values?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, loops

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that contains a dictionary, I'd like to iterate over the dictionary keys to create new columns named after the various keys. The issue come whens I try to get the nested list logic to fill those row values with the corresponding key values from the 'tags' column. Right now the code I have generates the column names, but fills all the rows with the same values. I thought .get() was supposed to retrieve the corresponding value on each iteration?

```
for x in df1['tags']:
    for e in x.values():
        df1[str(e)] = x.get(e)
```

[image: Column 'tags']

Comment: try, ``df1.tags.apply(pd.Series)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
   for e in row['tags']:
      df1.loc[i, e] = row['tags'][e]
```